# Android do null checks in view model that uses flow mapped to livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `viewModel` that receives a `Flow` from a service but before I invoke the service I need to do basic checks such as if `email` or `password` is empty return the view an error. How do I return `livedata` back to the view?

Here is my `viewModel` code -

```
private val viewState = LoginViewState()

    fun loginUser(email: String, password: String): LiveData<LoginViewState> {
        if (email.isEmpty()) {
           // This is not working
            return liveData {
                viewState.copy(loading = false, emailEmpty = true)
            }
        }
        // This works
        return loginService.performLoginAction(email, password).map {
            when (it) {
                ...
            }
        }.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
    }
```

As you see I do a basic check of if `email` is empty and if empty I return a `livedata` back to the view and the view does not receive anything. However when the service returns a `flow` and the `viewModel` maps it to `livedata` and returns to the view that works. How do I do basic check in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by myself -

I do the following and it works -

```
if (email.isEmpty()) {
            return liveData {
                emit(viewState.copy(loading = false, emailEmpty = true))
            }
        }
```

I was missing the `emit` function basically